# How to Display list from Firestore in an item builder

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The getIngredients() method below returns a list from firestore.

```
Future getIngredients() async {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('ingredients')
        .where("name", isEqualTo: widget.dish_name.toString().toLowerCase()).getDocuments();
  }
```

Now I want to display this list in an item builder below:

```
 new ListView.builder(
                  itemExtent: 90,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return SingleIngredient(
                        ingredient_name: snapshot.data[index].ingredients,
                      );
                  });
```

I get the following error message:

> _FutureBuilderState#7cbda): I/flutter (12164): Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'length'. I/flutter (12164):
>   Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot' I/flutter (12164): Tried
>   calling: length

Here's the scturcture of my firestore. I am fetching the ingredients list:

[image]

***UPDATE***
I have updated the code but I am only getting the first item from the list of ingredients (i.e, Onions). I want the itembuilder to build each item in the list because I am trying to display an image and the the ingredient list. That's what the SingleIngredient widget is doing. So, how can I loop through each list one by one?

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getIngredients(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.documents[index];

                  return SingleIngredient(
                    // Access the fields as defined in FireStore
                    ingredient_name: user.data['ingredients'][index].toString(),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                !snapshot.hasData) {
              // Handle no data
              return Center(
                child: Text("No users found."),
              );
            } else {
              // Still loading
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to use `snapshot.data.documents` to access the documents of a query, so to get the length it will be `snapshot.data.documents.length`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example using `StreamBuilder` where i retrieve all documents from a collection and build a `ListView` to show them:

```
Widget buildUserList(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.documents[index];

                return ListTile(
                    // Access the fields as defined in FireStore
                    title: Text(user.data['firstName']),
                    subtitle: Text(user.data['lastName']),
                );
            },
        );
    } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && !snapshot.hasData {
        // Handle no data
        return Center(
            child: Text("No users found."),
        );
    } else {
        // Still loading
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder(
        stream:
            Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: buildUserList,
    )
)
```

or

```
Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future:
            Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments(),
        builder: buildUserList,
    )
)
```

Comment: The example you provided will prints single value fields. I want to print and store an array field. How do I do that?

Comment: You can return any Widget from the builder to display any kind of data you want. It doesn't have to be a `ListView`. All fields in `DocumentSnapshot.data` are `dynamic` so you can just do something like `List<String> list = snapshot.data.documents[index].data['myListKey'];` to retrieve the value.

Comment: Both will actually work. If you want to use `getDocuments()` you need a `FutureBuilder` since that returns a `Future<QuerySnapshot>`. Here calling `snapshots()` makes it return a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`

Comment: Exactly, I am using FututeBuilder but how do I display the results without using streambuilder? Can you kindly provide me an example which access an array field from firestore?

Comment: They are used basically the same way. Updated answer

Comment: I guess my question is, inside the ListTile,  if I want to get the ingredient list, will I just have to do ingredients: Text(user.data['ingredients'])?

Comment: Yes, just assign that to a List like what I wrote in the first comment.

Comment: I want the   itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length, to return the length of ingredient list as opposed to the length of the document. How do I do that?

Comment: If you are sure you will only have one document returned, use `snapshot.data.documents.single.data['ingredients'].length`

Comment: And how should I access each item ? ingredient_name: ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187386/discussion-between-swiftingduster-and-bangbang).

Answer (score 0):

Dart does not know what type you are returning from the Future so it's interpreting it as a dynamic object, which has no length getter on it. Change your method

```
Future getIngredients() async {
return Firestore.instance
    .collection('ingredients')
    .where("name", isEqualTo: widget.dish_name.toString().toLowerCase()).getDocuments();
```

}

**To**

```
Future<List<YourType>> getIngredients() async {
return Firestore.instance
    .collection('ingredients')
    .where("name", isEqualTo: widget.dish_name.toString().toLowerCase()).getDocuments();
```

}

Where YourType is the type that's returned from the getDocuments() function. You might need to do a toList() on it as well.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I implement your changes: 

The return type 'Future<QuerySnapshot> isnt a 'Future<List<String>>' as defined by the method getIngredients

Comment: @bangbang are you returning a List<String> what does getDocuments return?

Comment: Please look at the firestore document structure attached. I am returning a list of ingredients (Strings).

Comment: If I change my query to something like this: 

Future getIngredients() async {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('ingredients')
        .where("name", isEqualTo: widget.dish_name.toString().toLowerCase()).snapshots()
        .listen((data) =>
        data.documents.forEach((doc) => print(doc["ingredients"])));
  }

I am able to get a list of ingredients. I just dont know how to display it in a widget

Answer (score 0):

use FirestoreListView from [flutterfire_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_ui) package

```
final usersQuery = Firestore.instance
    .collection('ingredients')
    .where("name", isEqualTo: widget.dish_name.toString().toLowerCase());

FirestoreListView<Map<String, dynamic>>(
query: usersQuery,
itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
Map<String, dynamic> recipes = snapshot.data();
    return SingleIngredient(ingredient_name: recipes['ingredients'].first,);
// using 'first' because ingredients is an array
   },
);
```

Find documentation [here.](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/ui/firestore/)

Answer (score -1):

```
body: StreamBuilder(
stream: Firestore.instance
    .collection('ups')
.where('pc',
isEqualTo: widget.post.data["pc"])
.snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
return Center(
child: Text("Loading..."),
);
} else {
final ups = snapshot.data.documents;
List<String> stateWidget = [];
for (var message in ups) {
final stateText = message.data['state'];
// final stateCollection = Text('$stateText');
stateWidget.add(stateText);
}enter code here
return  ListView(
children: stateWidget
    .map((data) => ListTile(`enter code here`
title: Text(data),
onTap: () => {_selectedItem(data)}))
    .toList(),`enter code here`
)
```

Comment: Hi @miriam, can you indent the code to make it more readable. Some closing braces seems to be missing and the `enter code here` string seems wrong.