# Flutter page does not reload when I update the list on the ListView

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, listview, dart

Sorry in advance as the issue might be something very small.

So i have got this file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '../utils/authentication.dart';
import '../utils/stated.dart';
import 'user_info_screen.dart';


class CategoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoryScreen({Key? key, required User user, required Stated stated, required int intel})
      : _user = user, _stated = stated, _intel = intel,
        super(key: key);

  final User _user;
  final Stated _stated;
  final int _intel;

  @override
  _CategoryScreenState createState() => _CategoryScreenState();
}

class _CategoryScreenState extends State<CategoryScreen> {
  late User _user;
  late Stated _stated;
  late int _intel;
  bool loaded = false;
  List<Widget> rows = [];
  int limit = 2;
  var temporal = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    _user = widget._user;
    _stated = widget._stated;
    _intel = widget._intel;
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //print(_user.photoURL);

    if (!loaded) {
      print(rows.toString());
      setState(() {
        // Rows ==============================================================================================================

        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('listings').where('category', isEqualTo: _stated.CATEGORIES[_intel]).orderBy('views', descending: true).limit(limit).get().then((value) {

          rows.add(
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0, right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
                child: Text(
                  _stated.CATEGORIES[_intel],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    letterSpacing: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              )
          );
          value.docs.forEach((element) {
            if (element.data()['reviewed'] == false) {

              rows.add(
                  Container(
                    height: 30.0,
                  )
              );
              rows.add(
                  OutlineButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DisplayScreen(
                              user: _user,
                              stated: _stated,
                              intel: element.id,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget> [
                          Container(
                            height: 175.0,
                            width: 200,
                            child: Image.network(element.data()['image']['0']),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 75.0,
                            width: 200,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  element.data()['title'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    letterSpacing: 2,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      )
                  )
              );
            }
          });
        }).then((e) {
          loaded = true;
          print(rows.toString());
          if (rows.length == limit) {
            rows.add(
                Container(
                  height: 30.0,
                )
            );
            rows.add(
                OutlineButton(
                    onPressed: () async {

                    },
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget> [
                        Container(
                          height: 250.0,
                          width: 200,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Load More',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  letterSpacing: 2,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],
                    )
                )
            );
          }
        });
      });
      // End of setState =============================================================
    }
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          actions: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () async {

                User? user =
                await Authentication.signInWithGoogle(context: context);

                if (user != null) {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => UserInfoScreen(
                        user: user,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                child: _user.photoURL != null
                    ? ClipOval(
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    child: Image.network(
                      (_user.photoURL!).replaceAll("=s96-c", "=s1000-c"),
                      height: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                    : ClipOval(
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        size: 50,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            children: rows,
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

The page loads fine without errors, however the concept of the page is that is the "Category" page for my app, the idea is that once rerouted to this page i create a listview to not leave the screen blank, and run a Firebase call to load the items, currently is set to a limit of 2 items(for testing), and i create card like containers that hold the data of the items.

Issue is that all the items in the list are stored in 'rows', and this variable is updated as i check by printing it on the console, however the page on the screen does not update.

I do believe its a common or basic thing that i am forgetting/missing because there are no errors, or probably how i am setting the list, but every time i search for this issue online no body has had this issue.

How do i make the list on screen show?

PS: as android studio is, if I press CTRL-S to save the code it also hot-reloads the simulator, and for a split second in the simulator the list shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of business logic inside the build method that blocks your UI rendering until you get the result from Firestore - this is bad and definitely not a way to go.

You should start by learning more about FutureBuilder or any state management solution on retrieving data and building the UI based on state changes. I would recommend starting from this Codelab (or any other Firestore + Flutter tutorial) just to get the idea of how to work with Firestore in Flutter: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter

Comment: You were right, didn't quite understand it but after seing this example i got the memo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385713/how-to-display-list-from-firestore-in-an-item-builder